# How to redirect a json response from one php page to another?

Tags: php, ajax, json

The scenario is as follows: There are two php pages named page1.php and page2.php.onClick of a button in page3.php a ajax request is sent to page1.php. I have to redirect this request to page2.php where the processing takes places. Now I need to get the processed data in page1.php and convert it to json and send the json response to page3.php. So page1.php acts like an intermediate page for the communication between page3.php and page2.php.

If I use header("Location:page2.php") in page1.php then I cannot get the processed data from page2.php.(As I need the processed data in page1.php)
Please suggest how this can be done?

Comment: That's not feasible. If you redirect from a php page to another, a 301 http response will be sent to the ajax call. Anyway, I can't see the point to make a redirect between two php pages. Maybe you could solve with a conditional include/require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just `require` page2.php?

What I mean is:

```
page3.php  ->  AJAX request to page1.php
page1.php  ->  $request = json_decode(AJAX request from page3.php)
               require page2.php
page2.php  ->  process $request
               populate $response
page1.php  ->  echo json_encode($response)
page3.php  ->  AJAX response from page1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

on **page2.php**  write  `echo json_enode($return_data)`

and retrieve on **page3.php** by `json_decode($output,true);` and store into `$_SESSION` variable and

on **page3.php** retrieve data by `$_SESSION['']`

Reference:

**[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

**[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can redirect an ajax request like that. Please show me otherwise if someone knows though. From what I know about these things, it sounds to me like you are using a bad way to do this.

I would suggest this as an example:

- Create a class to handle your
  processing. The reason why, is
  because you may use the same thing
  more than once and you do not have to
  duplicate the code then.
- You can then on page 1, require this class file like this `require_once('path/to.file');`
- So next, the function or piece of script that handles your ajax request on page 1 you can create a new instance of your processing class and pass the data to it. Do the processing and return the data.

Get where I am going with this? No need to redirect, just contain your processing in an object.

Here is an example

```
$processing = new Processing($_POST);
$return_data = $processing->run();

return json_encode($return_data);
```